# Angular 7 Rxjs - In-Flight HTTP request not cancelling for subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I'm having trouble understanding why unsubscribing from a rxjs subscription with an added step does not cancel a in-flight http request.

Take a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-http-example-nx8fza

You'll notice in the network tab for chrome, one of the clicks cancels requests and the other does not.

```
 getJoke(): void {
    this.jokeSub = this.api.getData()
      .subscribe(data => this.joke = data);

    this.jokeSub.unsubscribe();
  }

  // This method does not cancel requests in flight because of the .add step.
  getJoke2(): void {
    this.jokeSub2 = this.api.getData()
      .subscribe(data => this.joke = data).add(console.log("Added step"));

    this.jokeSub2.unsubscribe();
  }
```

[image: cancel request]

Side Note: I came across this when I setting up an http interceptor in Angular 7 with rxjs 6. I couldn't cancel requests when my interceptor had any logic in the pipe. I think if can figure out why its not working here, I can answer my more specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.add` method adds teardown logic and returns a **new** subscription for that teardown logic. That new subscription is added as an inner subscription to the initial one. So these subscription have parent-child relations, and if you unsubscribe from parent — child is also disposed.

Though unsubscribing from children wont complete the parent.

Heres an explanation from the [docs on add method](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Subscription#add)

> Returns the Subscription used or created to be added to the inner subscriptions list. This Subscription can be used with remove() to remove the passed teardown logic from the inner subscriptions list.

Heres a playground for that. Try commenting out some timeouts:

```js
const { timer } = rxjs;
const { finalize, take } = rxjs.operators;

const startedAt = Date.now();

const a = timer(0, 300).pipe(
    finalize(createTeardown('a')),
    take(10)
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);

const b = a.add(createTeardown('b'));
const c = a.add(createTeardown('c'));

// Try commenting out some of these
setTimeout(()=>a.unsubscribe(), 1000);
setTimeout(()=>b.unsubscribe(), 1000);
setTimeout(()=>c.unsubscribe(), 1000);


function createTeardown(name) {
  return () => console.log(name, Date.now() - startedAt);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.4.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

To fix your particular code example, you'll need to store original subscription separately:

```js
getJoke2(): void {
  this.jokeSub2 = this.api.getData()
    .subscribe(data => this.joke = data); // parent subscription (a)

  this.jokeSub2
    .add(() => console.log('Child teardown logic')); // child subscription (b)

  this.jokeSub2.unsubscribe();
}
```

*NOTE: this basically duplicates AlesD's answer. Joining this into one answer for transparency*

Hope this helps

Comment: Kos, if the inner subscription is disposed why does the http request not cancel?

Comment: @starfighter104, the parent-child relation is as follows: `a->b->c`. Disposing `a`, disposes `b` and `c`. While disposing child `b`, only disposes grandchild `c`. In your example you're disposing a child subscription. That doesn't affect parent subscription

Comment: Store your root subscription in a separate variable and unsubscribe from it.

Comment: is jokeSub2 not my root subscription?

Comment: @starfighter104, no because you've chained the `subscribe(...).add(...)` — so the `jokeSub2` stores result of the `.add(...)` method.

Comment: To explain in terms of the playground: `jokeSub2` stores `b`, not `a`.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes sense! Could you provide me with a code snippet just for clearer communication on how to store the root subscription?

Comment: @starfighter104, I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: it is similar to @AlesD 's answer, just with comments. Also, please see updated stackblitz that AlesD provides

Answer (score 1):

As already the other answer explains this is how rxjs works I add also how you should change your code to make it work like the first sample.

```
getJoke2(): void {
    this.jokeSub2 = this.api.getData()
      .subscribe(data => this.joke = data);
    this.jokeSub2.add(console.log("Added step"));

    this.jokeSub2.unsubscribe();
}
```

Also a [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-http-example-vwwzym?file=app/app.component.ts) to a fork of your StackBlitz where you can see it works.